# laravel repository query auth users records

Tags: php, laravel, repository, eloquent

Hi I have set up a repository in laravel, when I query the projects table on its own for example `return  Project::all();` I am returned with all the records in the database. However I wanted to query the logged in users records and only retrieve those records so I am doing this as so `return Auth::user()->projects;` however when I do this I get the following error in my laravel log:

```
[2014-09-01 20:26:44] production.ERROR: exception 
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 
'Acme\Repositories\Auth' not 
found' in /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/Acme/Repositories/DbProjectRepository.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

My full repository is as follows:

```
<?php
 namespace Acme\Repositories;

use Project;

class DbProjectRepository implements ProjectRepositoryInterface  {


    public function getAll()
    {
        return Auth::user()->projects;
    }


}
```

Project Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $projects = $this->project->getAll();
         echo View::make('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

Project View

```
@if (Auth::check())
    @if (count($projects) > 0)
   @foreach ($projects as $project)
{{ $project->project_name }}
 @endforeach 
   @else
      <p>No records, would you like to create some...</p>
@endif
    @endif
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: If you are using Laravel's Auth, you can try `\Auth::user()` (add '\' before Laravel's core classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `namespace` and `Auth` is not within that `namespace`, you may just add the `Auth` in your `use` statement like:

```
namespace Acme\Repositories;

use Project, Auth;

class DbProjectRepository implements ProjectRepositoryInterface  {

    public function getAll()
    {
        return Auth::user()->projects;
    }
}
```

without `use` keyword, you may specify the global `namespace` using `\` like:

```
public function getAll()
{
    return \Auth::user()->projects;
}
```